# Which ephemeral ports are used with raw sockets

Tags: networking, kernel, port

Referring to [How source ports get assigned](https://superuser.com/questions/1118735/how-are-source-ports-determined-and-how-can-i-force-it-to-use-a-specific-port), I do know, how the local port is determined. (=> Random free ephemeral port).

However, why does my raw socket using `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)` get port `6` assigned?

`ss -lnp` shows: `tcp UNCONN 0 0 0.0.0.0:6 0.0.0.0:* users:(("exe",pid=13164,fd=5))`

Do I create the socket incorrectly (because IPPROTO_TCP is defined with `=6` in `linux/in.h`)? Or are RAW_SOCKETS defaulted to port `6` if available?

I am Using Ubuntu 4.15 if that's important.

Comment: Raw sockets are not port specific, but protocol specific (they can be used to implement new IP protocols in user space) so I strongly suspect the protocol is encoded in what `ss` shows as the port. It's easy to test: Use a different protocol (including unassigned numbers) and have a look at what `ss` shows. Or use nc etc. to send a few TCP packets to/from unrelated ports and see if you receive them.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the `6` in `ss` just seem to tell me, that I used `IPPROTO_TCP`... yes. Using `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 123)` `ss` outputs `??? UNCONN 0 0 0.0.0.0:123 0.0.0.0:* users:(("exe",pid=10039,fd=3))` so it makes sense. I'll write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dirkt commented, the socket is not-port bound and `displays` the protocol aftert the local IP instead of the port (which is not there obviously).

using `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 123)`,  `ss` outputs `??? UNCONN 0 0 0.0.0.0:123 0.0.0.0:* users:(("exe",pid=10039,fd=3))`

Also, testing with other numbers as the third argument to `socket()`, `ss` shows that as the local `port`.